# How can I open a locked door with a half destroyed cylinder lock?

Tags: doors, lock

On my new bought property there's a locked door whose cylinder lock was destroyed by drilling in it from both sides. The hole indoors is 24 mm deep, the hole outdoors 23 mm. Now the plugs on each side are loose and can rotate without opening the door, they are both obviously not attached to the actuator any more. Unfortunately, the hinge pins also can't be removed undamaged when the door is closed. What can I do to open the door without damaging it?

## Photos

#### Lock from indoors

[image: Lock from indoors]

#### Lock from outdoors

[image: Lock from outdoors]

#### Image from [wilka.de](http://www.wilka.de/cylinder-and-keying-systems/cylinder-types/1488-short-cylinder)

[image]

#### Technical Drawing from [wilka.de](http://www.wilka.de/cylinder-and-keying-systems/cylinder-types/1488-short-cylinder)

[image: Technical Drawing]

## Files

- [PDF with General Notes about the lock](http://www.wilka.de/bilder/upload/Standard/superClient/Allgemeine_Hinweisei24k8pxp.pdf)
- [PDF with Explanation of Drilling Protection methods](http://www.wilka.de/bilder/upload/Standard/superClient/ABH_IVi24k8pe9.pdf), the lock may be equipped with **ABH I**, **III**, or **V**.

Comment: Can you reach back and access the actuator, or are the holes not deep enough for that?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added the hole depths in the question, however although arithmetically I should be able to access the actuator, I'm not sure about that. Do you propose to drill further?

Comment: You should be able to get it by spinning the core until the actuator completely blocks the hole...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The core can be spinned, however obviously is **not** attached to the actuator any more, the cores are much too loose for that.

Comment: Ouch.  You might be able to get the actuator to turn slowly by poking at it through the hole then...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I tried it, but either the actuator sits too tight or it's jammed by the drill holes or the holes do not reach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 24mm, the holes do not reach the actuator.

If you carefully examine the sides of the drilled holes, you should be able to see the remains of the nickel-plated anti-drill pins. If you don't see them, your lock is probably ABH-I.

I think the first thing to try is to remove one of the cores completely. Drive a hardened steel screw into the key slot and pry the core out with a claw hammer or pry bar (aka crowbar).

You will need to push a metal plug or tool into the drilled hole to keep the core from turning while you force the steel screw into the key slot. Obviously the screw should be a star drive, or even a hex head if you can find one. Try to get it at least 15mm into the core.

It looks like you should try the indoor side first, as you can use the lock housing as a fulcrum without crushing the door panel. Use a scrap of plywood to protect the door when prying.

If you can't get either core out, the next best thing would be to drill all the way through both cores and the actuator. Don't just extend the existing holes at their current diameter -- unlike the original driller, you are not trying to cut away working parts of the lock -- but use a much smaller drill size. You only need a hole large enough to fit a steel rod, like a piece of bass piano wire. Or, you may be able to use the drill itself to tie the cores to the actuator.

Add an assistant and a little coordination to turn both cores in the same direction at the same time, and the door should open with minimum fuss.

Comment: Using the screw-and-prybar trick I was able to pull one of the cores out, after removing broken parts inside the core hole I had access to the activator and was able to turn it using a screwdriver, and the door opened. Thanks a lot!